# Can't get back to initial list after adding search functionnality in flutter

Tags: flutter

i'm trying to fetch users through a search bar! the search function works perfectly but everytime I try to remove some letters it doesn't get me back to the intial full list of users.

Textfield for search:

```
TextField(
                  controller: searchController,
                  decoration: InputDecoration(
                      prefixIcon: const Icon(Icons.search),
                      hintText: 'Search for users',
                      border: OutlineInputBorder(
                          borderRadius: BorderRadius.circular(12),
                          borderSide: BorderSide(color: Colors.grey))),
                  onChanged: (value) => searchUser(value),
                ),
```

Search function:

```
void searchUser(String query) {
    final suggstions = users?.where((user) {
      final userName = user.name.toLowerCase();
      final input = query.toLowerCase();
      return userName.contains(input);
    }).toList();
    setState(() {
      users = suggstions;
    });
  }
```

initState:

```
@override
  void initState() {
    super.initState();
    getUsersFromDatabase();
  }
```

I'd be grateful if anyone can help!

Answer (score 0):

since you only fetch the list once in initState, then you have to separate in to different list.

```
List users = [];
List showUser =[];
```

in your `getUsersFromDatabase()`

```
users = your api response list;
showUser = users;
```

---

for the search function you have to filter the `users` and assign it to `showUser`

```
void searchUser(String query) {
  if( String query == '') {
   setState(() { // setState to update UI
     showUser = users); // when empty string, show all users
   });
   return;  // return it, so the code below will not executed
  }

   // filter the  users, and the result  assign  to show users.
   // so your list of user will only change once in initState
    final suggstions = users?.where((user) {
      final userName = user.name.toLowerCase();
      final input = query.toLowerCase();
      return userName.contains(input);
    }).toList();
    setState(() {
      showUsers = suggstions;
    });
  }
```

last, display the `showUser` not the `users`

```
ListView(
  children: showUser.map()
  .....
```